# HTML scrollable div hides header

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create an infinite height contenteditable div inside a parent div, which displays a scrollbar whenever content reaches the end of the screen. However, I'm running into a problem. If the text inside the contenteditable div (`page`) reaches the end of the screen, it hides the header (`menu`) and displays the bottom of the page, but it's impossible to get back again unless I refresh the page. Also, the scrollbar doesn't allow scrolling.

[Here's a fiddle with everything so far](https://jsfiddle.net/e6r6f835/1/), and an explanation inside.

How can I get it so that the scrollbar appears on the parent (`content`) div, filling 100% of the screen's remaining height without overflowing, and have it so that when I add content, it doesn't hide the menu?

EDIT: If you're going to immediately downvote my question, tell me how I can improve it.

Comment: You could set an explicit height for `#page` that doesn't exceed the `body`-element and set `overflow: auto;` on `#page` as well.

Comment: You can improve your question by following the rules of the site: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  Also: Links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.  If you can't take time to read the rules then don't complain when you get downvoted.

Comment: For the record, I'm not complaining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

/* ============================================================
    Default Window CSS
============================================================ */

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

html {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100% !important;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
html * {
    color: #222;
}
p {
    font-size: 13px;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 20px;
}
body {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100% !important;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 0.5s;
}
body {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Arial, sans-serif;
}
#container {
    height: 100%;
}
#content {
    background: #eee;
    font-size: 10px;
    min-height: 100%;
    padding: 32px;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
#page {
          font-size: 14px;
    background: #fff;
    width: 800px;
    padding: 32px;
    outline: none;
    resize: none;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 64px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    height: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
#footer {
    display: flex;
    height: 32px;
    padding: 8px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

/* ============================================================
    MENU
============================================================ */
#menu {
        position: fixed;
    cursor: default;
    text-align: center;
    background: linear-gradient(#fbfbfb, #efefef);
    box-shadow: inset #bfbfbf 0 -1px 0 0;
    height: 28px;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 100%;
}
#titlebar {
    top: 6px;
}
#titlebar {
    position: relative;
    top: 8px;
}
#titlebar > p {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="menu">
        <div id="titlebar">
            <p>Title</p>
        </div>
        <div id="controls" onmousedown="app.cancelMoveEvent()">
            <!-- Close, Minimize, Maximise -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="page" contenteditable="true">This should appear on 100% of the screen's remaining height and be scrollable, appearing as an endless page to write in. However, when this happens, the menu at the top of the screen, as well as the top arrow of the scrollbar, disappears, and there is no way to get it back. Only the parent div and the contents should be scrollable. Paste this text a few times to see what I mean.This should appear on 100% of the screen's remaining height and be scrollable, appearing as an endless page to write in. However, when this happens, the menu at the top of the screen, as well as the top arrow of the scrollbar, disappears, and there is no way to get it back. Only the parent div and the contents should be scrollable. Paste this text a few times to see what I mean.This should appear on 100% of the screen's remaining height and be scrollable, appearing as an endless page to write in. However, when this happens, the menu at the top of the screen, as well as the top arrow of the scrollbar, disappears, and there is no way to get it back. Only the parent div and the contents should be scrollable. Paste this text a few times to see what I mean.This should appear on 100% of the screen's remaining height and be scrollable, appearing as an endless page to write in. However, when this happens, the menu at the top of the screen, as well as the top arrow of the scrollbar, disappears, and there is no way to get it back. Only the parent div and the contents should be scrollable. Paste this text a few times to see what I mean.This should appear on 100% of the screen's remaining height and be scrollable, appearing as an endless page to write in. However, when this happens, the menu at the top of the screen, as well as the top arrow of the scrollbar, disappears, and there is no way to get it back. Only the parent div and the contents should be scrollable. Paste this text a few times to see what I mean.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
    
    </div>
</div>
```

I have changed the css of #page and #menu. Now the menu is fixed and the page has the scroller in it if the content grows.

Answer (score 0):

Simply adding `overflow-y: scroll;` to `#container` seems to fix the problem for me. It makes the regular scrollbar work correctly, and allows the header to be shown when scrolling up.

Comment: This adds a scrollbar to the entire page, including the menu. I only want the scrollbar to appear in the parent div of the page.